# Proving the set of order-automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As stated in the title, I am trying to prove that $$\mathcal{A}:=\{f\mid f\in\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{Q}\mid f\text{ is an automorphism of }(\mathbb{Q},<)\}\sim\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{Q}.$$

I have already tried constructing an embedding $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}$, by looking at intervals at which the automorphism scales the numbers by a constant factor, but this really doens't work.

Can someone give a *hint* on solving this?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** You can write $\Bbb Q$ as the countable union of *disjoint* open intervals, and each of them is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ again. Now use this to encode binary sequences.